# Is there any suitable approach to solve the LCPN method in hierarchical classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, multiclass-classification

I have a multi-class problem. I want to solve this problem using the LCPN (Local Classifier per Parent Node) method of heirachical classification. Therefore, I have manually divided the original dataset into a hierarchy of 2 levels. Level 1 has, four parent classes & each of the parent classes have child classes (level 2). Does anyone know if the below mentioned approach is correct to solve this problem?

1. divide the entire dataset into train set(70%) and test set(30%)
2. oversample the training set (since it’s imbalanced)
3. train the parent classifier using the resampled training set & test it on the entire test set

for each of the 4 sub classifiers under the parent classifier:
4. take the resampled training set (the dataset obtained after resampling, at step 2. )
5. filter the instances that belong only to the particular sub classifier. Because the resampled
   dataset has instances that belong to all the 4 sub classifiers.
6. create a dataset using those instances. Including features & labels.
7. split the created dataset, into sub-training(70%) and sub-test set(30%)
8. oversample the sub-training set (because the classes are imbalanced)
9. train the model with the oversampled sub-training set at step 8., & test it using the sub-test set